# Navbar is not sticking

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am using materialize.css, materialize.js, and jquery 2.1.1.

I am trying to construct a sticky navbar after my .jumbotron1. I have the css all there but the jquery doesn't seem to be running.

I followed this tutorial : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/forum-tip-create-a-sticky-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2

the css

```
body {
  padding-top: 400px;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

/* navbar styling */
nav.navbarSticky {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  z-index: 998;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/*sticky navbar styling*/
.jumbotron1 .stuck {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
 }

/*lineup styling*/
.lineup1position {
  position: relative;
}
.lineup1 {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

the html

```
<!--jumbotron 1-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 valign-wrapper jumbotron1">
      <p class="valign center-block center-align">
        Andrea + Fiance<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--navbar-->
<nav class="navbarSticky">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul id="nav-mobile">
      <li><a href="#">line up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tickets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">history</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">venue</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">details</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!--lineup1-->
<div class="container lineup1position">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s8 offset-s2 lineup1">
      <p class="center-align">
        lineup<br>
        andrea - fiance<br>
        made of honor - best man<br>
        bridesmaid - groomsman - bridesmaid - groomsman<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the javascript

```
  var sticky = $(".navbarSticky")
  var stuck = "stuck";
  var hdr = $('.jumbotron1').height();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
      sticky.addClass(stuck);
    } else {
      sticky.removeClass(stuck);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position:relative is overriding position:fixed
```

In this css class

```
nav.navbarSticky {
      margin-top: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
```

Here position relative is overriding `position:fixed` in `stuck` class
Take a look at this snippet

[image: View from Console]

So I made this changes

New classes

```
#topContainer{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1001;
}


.stuck {
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  top: 10px;
  z-index:1001;
  position:fixed !important;
 }
.fixContainer{
  position:fixed !important;
  top:0px;
}
```

**HTML**

Added `id` attribute to top container

```
<div class="container" id ="topContainer">
     // rest of code
```

**JS**

```
 var sticky = $(".navbarSticky")
  var stuck = "stuck";
  var hdr = $('.jumbotron1').height();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log($(this).scrollTop(),hdr)
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
    $("#topContainer").addClass("fixContainer") //Change here
      sticky.addClass(stuck);
    } else {
     $("#topContainer").removeClass("fixContainer") //Change here
      sticky.removeClass(stuck);
      }
  });
```

You can check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nxjom38L/2/).

Currently the `div.lineup1position` is scrolling below `li` because of z-index property attached to `li` Since I am not sure how `div.lineup1position` is going to scroll so leaving it on you

Edit: `addClass` & `removeClass` are properly used.So removing that part

Comment: I was working with the dev tools and discovered this overriding of the position: fixed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your sticky class is not on the correct element

CSS (only works if `.jumbotron1` has `.stuck`):

```
/*sticky navbar styling*/
.jumbotron1 .stuck {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
 }
```

jQuery (is stetting `.stuck` to `.navbarSticky`)

```
sticky.addClass(stuck);
```

---

**Edit:** In response to the comment below.

You want `.navbarSticky` to be stuck, and you are using the same styling as `.jumbotron1`, so you need a CSS selector like

```
.jumbotron1,
.stuck {
```

Also bear in mind that since your jumbotron is set to `width: 100%;` that once you add the comma, your nav may be under the jumbotron. I forget the natural z-index order of html, but in any case, to fix it, add:

```
.stuck {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

This, BTW, you only add to `.stuck` do not add it to `.jumbotron1`.

Comment: So should I should separate the css styling for .jumbtron1 and .stuck?

Comment: If you want to apply the same styles to both `.jumbotron1` and `.stuck.`, use a comma. ie `.jumbotron1, .stuck`. Generally speaking you also put a newline there, but SO comments don't allow new lines, so I can't show that.

Comment: `.a.b` is an element with both classes. `.a .b` is a `b` element inside an `a` element. `.a, .b` is both `a` element and `b` element, without any stated relation between them.

Comment: I added a comma into the styling, still not working. And for the jQuery, I do want the .stuck properties to be added to .navbarSticky.

Comment: @grandpakong Without seeing what you are seeing, I can only guess, but take a look at my edit above and see if that fixes it.